# jQuery header text change "Show" "Hide"

Tags: jquery, accordion

Hello i need to change the header text of my jQuery accordian to "Show" when it is closed and to "Hide" when it is open. Please help me.

here's my code:

```
$(function() {
   $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: false });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML as well.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2508239/43671 specially the  ui.newHeader and  ui.oldHeader

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery UI: Accordion callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508163/jquery-ui-accordion-callbacks)

Answer (score 1):

Use Accordion callbacks :

```
$( "#accordion" ).on( "accordionchange", function(event, ui) {   
    var isCollapsed = $(this).find('.ui-state-active').length;
    if(isCollapsed){
         //open state 
    }else{
        //close state
    }
});
```

And here is the [demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6mSA/203/)

Comment: This didn't work for me using .on() but it did work when I changed that to .bind(). Now I'm trying to figure out the best way to change the h3 text for the appropriate section only.